# Using Gears for Geolocation in Webview? (for 1.5 phones)

Tags: java, android, geolocation, google-gears

I was able to setup geolocation accessibility in my webview for any android phone running 2.0 and up easily. However I really need to get this feature working on 1.5 and 1.6 phones as well. From what i've read it seems like this feature used to be accomplished with "Gears" and apparently there is a way to use `addJavascriptInterface` to implement this. I can't seem to find any examples anywhere. I'm actually suprised there isn't more information on this or at least easy to find information.

Comment: Hi,

can someone post an example of the geolocation in webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what i've read it seems like this
>   feature used to be accomplished with
>   "Gears" and apparently there is a way
>   to use addJavascriptInterface to
>   implement this.

No, there is not. Gears is not supported in `WebView`, only in the Browser application.